# Fullcalendar is not displaying events

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, fullcalendar

I have a problem with FullCalendar where it doesn't display my events. I have an idea that the event data might be in the wrong format, but I can't see what should be.

The code below is a simplified version of my code:

```
jQuery('#cal').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'agendaDay',
                axisFormat: 'H', //,'h(:mm)tt',
                timeFormat: {
                    agenda: 'H' //h:mm{ - h:mm}'
                },

                firstHour: 18,
                eventSources: 
                   [{"id":64,"title":"TestUser","start":"2011-03-08T02:00:00.0000000","end":"2011-03-08T04:00:00.0000000","allDay":false},{"id":65,"title":"TestUser","start":"2011-03-07T10:00:00.0000000","end":"2011-03-07T12:00:00.0000000","allDay":false}]
                ,
                eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
                    jQuery('#divEventTitle').html(calEvent.title);
                    showEvent(calEvent);
                    jQuery('#divEvent').dialog();
                },
                theme: true,
                header: false,
                height: 450
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When passing event data directly, the property to use is "events" as opposed to "eventSources".

Also, you're telling it to show you "agendaDay" which will only show the current day in an hour by hour view.  As today is March 6th, and your events are for March 7th and 8th, they will not show for the initial page load.