# JQuery FullCalendar not rendering my events from my webservice, but will if added in manually!

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

**EDITED to display new functionality:**

I'm having a real problem with my fullCalendar at the moment, and cannot for the life of me figure out what's going wrong?

I'm using an ASP.NET generic handler to handle the AJAX request.

My fullCalendar is initialised as so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var now = new Date();
    $("#CalendarControl").fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
        allDaySlot: false,
        minTime: 7,
        maxTime: 20,
        firstDay: now.getDay(),
        events: "AjaxCalendarHandler.ashx?assessorIds=2"
        //events: [{id:1,title:"FLEPI01 Agent Office 1\\n17-21 London Street SP10 2NU",start:Date(1300620600000),end:Date(1300624200000),className:"2",allDay:false}]
    });
})
```

And my ashx file is:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class AjaxCalendarHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.Write(Instruction.GetCalendarData(context.Request.QueryString["assessorIds"], context.Request.QueryString["start"], context.Request.QueryString["end"]));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edited content is found here**
And that method is doing nothing more than this:

```
    public static string GetCalendarData(string assessorIds, string startString, string endString)
    {
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        json.Append("[");
        DateTime startDate, endDate;
        Double startDouble, endDouble;

        if (Double.TryParse(startString, out startDouble))
            startDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(startDouble);
        else if (!DateTime.TryParse(startString, out startDate))
            throw new ArgumentException("Start date must be specified");

        if (Double.TryParse(endString, out endDouble))
            endDate = ConvertFromUnixTimestamp(endDouble);
        else if (!DateTime.TryParse(endString, out endDate))
            throw new ArgumentException("End date must be specified");

        DataAccess m_daccess = new DataAccess();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[3];
        param[0] = new SqlParameter("@AssessorIds", assessorIds);
        param[1] = new SqlParameter("@StartDate", startDate);
        param[2] = new SqlParameter("@EndDate", endDate);

        m_daccess.Fetch("up_Instruction_GetCalendarData", out ds, param);
        if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
        {
            string jsonDelim = string.Empty;
            foreach (DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                fullCalendarDiaryEvent Event = new fullCalendarDiaryEvent(dr);
                json.Append(jsonDelim + Event.ToJSON());
                jsonDelim = ",";
            }
        }

        json.Append("]");
        return json.ToString();
    }

    private class fullCalendarDiaryEvent
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public double start { get; set; } // **Treat these as doubles, rather than dates, as the ToJSON() method deals with dates in a different manner to that required by fullCalendar!!! **
        public double end { get; set; }
        public string className { get; set; }
        public bool allDay { get { return false; } }

        public fullCalendarDiaryEvent() {
            this.id = -1;
            this.title = string.Empty;
            this.start = 0;
            this.end = 0;
            this.className = string.Empty;
        }
        public fullCalendarDiaryEvent(int _id, string _title, DateTime _start, DateTime _end, string _className)
            : this()
        {
            this.id = _id;
            this.title = _title;
            this.start = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(_start);
            this.end = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(_end);
            this.className = _className;
        }
        public fullCalendarDiaryEvent(DataRow data)
            : this()
        {
            if (data["Id"] != null) this.id = Convert.ToInt32(data["Id"]);
            if (data["title"] != null) this.title = Convert.ToString(data["title"]);
            if (data["start"] != null) this.start = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(Convert.ToDateTime(data["start"]));
            if (data["end"] != null) this.end = ConvertToUnixTimestamp(Convert.ToDateTime(data["end"]));
            if (data["className"] != null) this.className = Convert.ToString(data["className"]);
        }
    }
```

So, as you can see, the webservice is returning a string, that is EXACTLY the same as that commented line in the fullCalendar set-up script.

My problem, is that when that string is returned via the webservice, nothing is displayed on the calendar, but if I pass the event in direct as an array, it works fine (as in , uncomment the events line).

I don't know why this is the case, and there aren't actually any usuable samples for what the JSON content should look like IF returned from another page.

My frustration levels are so high at the moment, I really need help....

Many thanks.

P.S This is my first posting, so please be nice.

Comment: I don't know asp,but do you need to add this? json.Append("["); I suppose that the json.ToString will jsonify the string for you. Can yo check what you are getting in the JS part with firebug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing event data directly, the property to use is "events". When naming a source (such as your web service) you use "eventSources". See also: [Fullcalendar is not displaying events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211035/fullcalendar-is-not-displaying-events/)

Also, this line looks like a problem:

```
json.Append("[id:1,title:\"FLEPI01 Agent Office 1\\\\n17-21 London Street SP10 2NU\",start:Date(1300620600000),end:Date(1300624200000),className:\"2\",allDay:false}");
```

You're opening that JSON chunk with a "[" as opposed to a "{".

As for the rest of your ASP and how you're building the JSON, I am clueless--I know nothing of ASP and its mechanisms. That said, there has got to be some sort of JSON serialization method available to you--manually building JSON is very bad practice.

Finally, use Firebug to see if the AJAX request is being made. If it is, copy the response body and validate it at http://www.jsonlint.com/ . In your case, you'll find that your object-property names and string-values are not double quoted.

Comment: Sorry, typo on my part. I was trying to demonstrate the fact that the webservice data is treated differently to that of using data direct. When the following JSON is used in both cases, it works fine as 

`events: [{id:1,title:"FLEPI01 Agent Office 1\\n17-21 London Street SP10 2NU",start:Date(1300620600000),end:Date(1300624200000),className:"2",allDay:false}]`

but not when returned via 

`events: "webservice.aspx"`

Comment: And @JAAulde, the eventSources is no different to the events. Neither seemed to render my events. Cheers though, it might have worked?

Comment: Which was a typo on your part--the "events" versus "eventSources", or the JSON formatting? Have you tried both suggestions which I made? --edit: just saw your second comment.

Comment: Ok, well you need to do some debugging then. Run your code in Firefox and watch Firebug to see if the AJAX request is ever even made, and, if it is, copy the response body (should be your JSON) and validate it with http://www.jsonlint.com/

Comment: No problems.

Given the following JSON: `[{id:1,title:'FLEPI01 Agent Office 1 17-21 London Street SP10 2NU',start:1300320000,end:1300372092,className:'2',allDay:false}]` which is the output from the ashx file (from Firebug), I get the following error at JSONLint: **syntax error, unexpected TINVALID, expecting TSTRING or '}' at line 3
Parsing failed** 

Not sure what that means though?

Comment: Your object-property names and string-values are not double quoted. This is a requirement in JSON, though I am not crazy about it. Simple things like that are why manual builds of JSON are not recommended. I should have noticed those were missing earlier--my bad. Anyway, here is what your JSON would like like when valid (and formatted): http://pastie.textmate.org/private/3trootb5jyllkqqt8g3ww

Comment: @JAAulde Result. It would seem there were 2 things wrong:
1. My JSON had to wrapped in "key":"value" pairs (which I had tried before, to no luck), and my dates had to be UNIX dates (which they were, but seeminly not quite right). As you've helped, I'm not sure how to accept your comment as an answer, or do I just accept the answer? Cheers.

Comment: The reason it works without the double quoting when you put it right in your JS is that you're not using JSON there, you're using JS literal syntax. JSON is a serialization format which uses JS literal styling. JSON is a string which, when parsed by a JSON parser must be valid and will become whatever language that parser produces.

Comment: I have been modifying the answer as I went in order to help anyone who comes along later, so feel free to accept the answer. ;)  Thanks, and glad you got it working.

Comment: @JAAulde Cheers mate, I really have been fighting with this all day, and you've joined it all up. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

My best quess is that the problem is how your response is sent from your Generic handler. It will still be in XML format, although you specified that the result is string. Your result will be something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
 JSON RESULT STRING
</string>
```

The only way that you can counter this is by stripping out the XML string on your client side.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and was beating my head against the wall to figure it out. It turned out that I needed to place double-quotes around all names of variables as well as quotes around the values assigned to those variables in my JSON string produced by my web service. I'm not sure if this will resolve your problem, but it worked for me. Also, some have made mention of a conflict in function naming that may exist with other JQuery plug-ins - try loading the calendar and event data in a bare jQuery/fullCalendar only page.